# javascript onblur() reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So I'm building a form with a minimum value of '5' (int), and I check the value with `onblur` if it is < 5. 
But when I trigger the function with `onblur="functionName()"`, it does not reset itself when the input is correct. (so input > 5).

```
    let minimalAmount = 5;
    let inputAmount = document.getElementById('amountInput');

    function checkAmount()
    {
        if (inputAmount.value < minimalAmount)
        {
            $('#amountAlert').html('Alert!');
        }
    }
```

This is what I tried so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean remove `Alert!` text ? If yes before `if-statement` put this line `$('#amountAlert').html("")`.

Comment: that did it, thanks!

Comment: `$('#amountAlert').text(+inputAmount.value < minimalAmount ? "Alert!" : "");`

Answer (score 0):

got it, thanks to Swati:

```
function checkAmount()
    {
        $('#amountAlert').html("");
        if (inputAmount.value < minimalAmount)
        {
            $('#amountAlert').html('Alert!');
        }
    }
```